# Can someone please assist me expand sed to extract required data?

Tags: sed

I must admit to sed seeming at times to be a bit of a black art to me; I found the following statement, which provided some of what I require.  I am assuming that sed is my handiest option as it will be in a bash script.

I have a file with lots of stuff, e.g.

```
LOTS_OF_OTHER_STUFF/STRING1\nOL8.0:2019-10-08-2/STRING2/LOTS_OF_OTHER_STUFF_HERE/STRING1\nOL8-slim:2019-10-08-20/SRING2/LOTS_OF_OTHER_STUFF
```

sed '/STRING1/!d;s//&\n/;s/.*\n//;:a;/STRING2/bb;$!{n;ba};:b;s//\n&/;P;D'

```
\nOL8.0:2019-10-08-2/
\nOL8-slim:2019-10-08-20/
```

What I require is:

```
8.0 2
8-slim 20
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are `\n` two char sequences or newlines here?

Comment: At any rate, [I get](https://ideone.com/T0RTeC) `OL8.0:2019-10-08-2/` and `OL8-slim:2019-10-08-20/SRING2/LOTS_OF_OTHER_STUFF`, it is different from what you claim

Comment: With GNU grep and paste: `grep -Po 'OL\K[^:]+|[0-9-]{11}\K[0-9]+' file | paste -d " " - -`

Comment: Hi Wiktor, they are character sequences. Oh yes, you are correct, this is an example rather than being exact excerpt. Actual text is "text":"BUILD PASS\nOL8.0:2019-10-08-2/oraclelinux-8.0-rootfs.tar.xz"

Comment: Above is again an excerpt but contains actual text sequence.

Comment: And my actual sed is sed '/PASS/!d;s//&\n/;s/.*\n//;:a;/oraclelinux/bb;$!{n;ba};:b;s//\n&/;P;D'

Comment: Cyrus: this looks good, however I am probably best also including PASS (STRING1 in my above example) with the grep.  When doing so however, it returns only one entry; I used PASS\nOL

Comment: I think if I can retrieve each occurrence of e.g. 8.0:2019-10-08-2 I can then extract all that I require with cut.  This saves me having to perform too many extractions.  I don't really mind which method is used as they both seem useful. Thanks for the assistance guys, much appreciated!

Comment: I've tried both methods and decided that grep is more intuitive (at least for me).  Cyrus: if you wish to make this an answer, I'll accept it as such. Wiktor, thanks for your reply too!